# SQL Server roles, schemas, users

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I've been trying to figure out why SQL Server has `db_owner` schema and `db_owner` role?  This is very confusing.  I've been searching for answers and so far this is how my understanding goes:

1. All tables and objects (such as constraints etc) belong to a schema.  `DBO` being the default schema.
2. A user may be given permission to edit each object or the schema.  A permission on the schema extends the permission to all objects within that schema.  So you don't have to grant permission on each individual object.
3. A role groups permissions together for convenience.

If any of this is incorrect let me know.  But I think so far so good.  Now my questions are:

1. What exactly is `db_owner` schema as seen in "Database User" dialog box of SQL Server Management Studio?  And on the same dialog, you define the "Default Schema" as `dbo`.  Why aren't the two the same?  If by default SQL Server uses `dbo` to create all objects under, what use is `db_owner`?
2. Why would a user want to own a schema?  You are assigning permissions/roles already.  What does owning `db_accessadmin` give you?
3. Can you give an example of when you create objects under `db_owner` schema and `db_accessadmin` schema?  In other words does anyone legitimately use those schemas?

Comment: Agreed.  It was ridiculous of them to create two different kinds of objects (a schema and role) with the same name.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

A SQL Server schema is simply container of objects, such as tables, stored procedures, etc.  A Database Role is a group of principals, such as windows logins, sql server users, etc.

The idea is you can have a role of say "IT", and have all IT users under that role.  Then you have can a schema called "IT", and have all tables that belong to IT under that.  Out of the box SQL Server creates matching schemas for each default user and role in the database, but I think the intention is you customize this to match the needs of your organization.

[This article](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/understanding-the-difference-between-owners-and-schemas-in-sql-server) has more information on the differences between owners and schemas.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254451/schema-owner-for-objects-in-ms-sql) on Stack Overflow may also be useful.

Comment: The article is pretty useful.  So from your answer I take it db_accessadmin schema is useless and is a side effect of db_accessadmin role.  Nobody creates tables under db_accessadmin schema, but instead you use a schema more relevant to your data.

Is there a list of what "ownership" of an object/schema gives you?  Is it all rights imaginable to that object?  Or could you be an owner with no read rights?

Comment: See this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189462.aspx for more details.  Specifically, "Objects created within a schema are owned by the owner of the schema, and have a NULL principal_id in sys.objects. Ownership of schema-contained objects can be transferred to any database-level principal, but the schema owner always retains CONTROL permission on objects within the schema."  So it looks like an owner always has full control over the objects in a schema.

Answer (score 3):

I am quoting the below from the following link.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669061(v=vs.110).aspx

> SQL Server ships with ten pre-defined schemas that have the same names as the built-in database users and roles. These exist mainly for backward compatibility. You can drop the schemas that have the same names as the fixed database roles if you do not need them. You cannot drop the following schemas:
>
> - `dbo`
> - `guest`
> - `sys`
> - `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`